# How to create a radio button to alt between settings in wp_options table

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

This is a "beginners" question so please bare with me... I need to create a radio button to switch/alt between options in wp_options. Basically a boolean that can enable/disable a setting for me.

I have a option called cf_current_list that saves the current list number, I need to change that value to 0 and then back to what it was last using this radio button, or any other button/switch to achieve this.

I assign this option value to a variable:    `$list = get_option('cf_current_list');`

I have no idea how to achieve this, it needs to be in front end though not a settings page in wp backend.

Answer (score 0):

fist of all set radio two radio button and give a name related like "cf_current_list" and have you set save button if yes then 
set code in functions.php file

like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['buuton_nm'])){
   if ( get_option( cf_current_list ) !== false ) {

     // The option already exists, so we just update it.
    update_option( cf_current_list, $_REQUEST['radio_btn_nm'] );

 } else {

          // The option hasn't been added yet. We'll add it with $autoload set to 'no'.
     $deprecated = null;
      $autoload = 'no';
      add_option( cf_current_list, $_REQUEST['radio_btn_nm'], $deprecated, $autoload );
  } 
}
```

try this code

Comment: It did not work, added code to functions.php and created inputs and save button on page but nothing happens. Can we move to chat?

Comment: input and button is in form tag ????

Comment: Your answer wasn't completely right but it helped me to get it working after some changes. +1

Comment: okey no problem